# Adding multiple numbers using java

Tags: java

I am trying to add numbers by scanning a line. I wanted the answer to be computed soon after i press "ENTER". What is the argument i should pass for the delimiter.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class add {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      int b=0;
      List<Integer> list  =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
      System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" ");
      while(sc.hasNextInt())
      {  
      list.add(sc.nextInt());
       }
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
         b += list.get(i);
      }
      System.out.println("The answer is" + b);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply write

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

This will compute the result as soon as the first non integer is entered...

---

If you really only want to read one line of input, you need to do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.nextLine();
for (String token : line.split("\\s+")) {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
}
// your for loop here...
```

Comment: Koneri said: `I wanted the answer to be computed soon after i press enter.` Your Scanner won't stop when user press enter.

Comment: What do you mean by `soon` ?

Comment: @kocko I think Koneri means `as soon as`.

Comment: I think he means "when", so this is a valid answer :)

Comment: @kocko i tried that already. it still waits for '/'(basically any character apart from integer to mark as end of inputs) to compute the result

Comment: The answer will be computed when user press `Ctrl-Z`, not `Enter`

Comment: Yes, i want it to be computed when i press enter. So do we have any parameter that we can pass to the delimiter

Comment: @jlordo basically i was trying to use list so that i do not have to specify the size. Now i am using array and then back to list.But anyways thank you i will use array now. But if you could explain me the line.split argument part. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Koneri: That's a regular expression matching multiple whitespaces. With the solution I have posted you don't need to specify any size...

Answer (score 0):

You're adding one item to the list and then your condition for loop stop is `i >= list.size()`; and `list.size()` is 0. That's not what you want, you'd like to try

```
int amount = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
```

Then you probably want to add items to list using `list.add(in.nextInt());`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class add {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      int b=0;
      List<Integer> list  =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
      System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[\r\n/]");
      while(sc.hasNextInt())
      {  
      list.add(sc.nextInt());

      }
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
         b += list.get(i);
      }
      System.out.println("The answer is" + b);
   }
}
```

Comment: use the argument "[\r\n/]" as it is the carriage return character